# C++ cannot convert from type bool(class) to bool

Tags: c++, function, compiler-errors, boolean

So I have an abstract superclass ReadWords, and 3 subclasses, FirstFilter, SecondFilter and ThirdFilter.

Readwords.h:

```
#ifndef _READWORDS_H
#define _READWORDS_H

using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

class ReadWords
{   public:

        ReadWords(char *filename);

        void close();

        string getNextWord();

        bool isNextWord();

        virtual bool filter(string word)=0;

        string getNextFilteredWord();

    private:
        ifstream wordfile;
        bool eoffound;
        string nextword;
        string fix(string word);

 };

 #endif
```

FirstFilter.h:

```
#ifndef _FIRSTFILTER_H
#define _FIRSTFILTER_H

using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "ReadWords.h"

class FirstFilter: public ReadWords
{   public:
       FirstFilter(char *filename);
       virtual bool filter(string word)
       {
           for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++){
                if (word[i]>='A'&&word[i]<='Z') return true;
           }
           return false;
       }
};

#endif
```

FirstFilter.cpp:

```
using namespace std;
#include "FirstFilter.h"

FirstFilter::FirstFilter(char *filename)
    :ReadWords(filename)
{
}
```

In the main function I create 3 objects of type FirstFilter, SecondFilter and ThirdFilter, and I have something like:

```
FirstFilter f1(file);
while(f1.isNextWord){
   //etc
}
```

I get this error for all 3 objects :

```
error: cannot convert 'ReadWords::isNextWord' from type 'bool (ReadWords::)()' 
to type 'bool'|
```

Any ideas ? Tell me if you need ReadWords.cpp too, I didn't put it cause it's a bit bigger.

Comment: `isNextWord` is a function.  It needs parens after it if you want to call it...unless you're trying to use it as a member function pointer (which is another thing entirely).

Comment: You are missing parentheses `while(f1.isNextWord())` here. Voting to close.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of

```
while(f1.isNextWord){
```

where isNextWord is used as a function pointer

write

```
while(f1.isNextWord() ){
```

where isNextWord is used as a function call